# Blender: Walk around sphere

Tags: python, blender, coordinate-transformation

In order to understand blender python game scripting, I currently try to build a scene in which one can walk around a sphere, using the FPSController structure from [this link](http://blender.pellej.com/bge/FPSController.blend). For gravity and FPSController orientation I tried to construct a python Controller, which currently looks like this:

```
def main():
    print("Started")

    controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    me = controller.owner

    distance, loc, glob = me.getVectTo((0,0,0))

    grav = controller.actuators['Gravity']

    strength = me['Gravity']
    force = strength*(distance*distance)*glob

    grav.force = force

    try:
        rot = Vector((0,0,-1)).rotation_difference(glob).to_matrix()
    except Exception as E:
        print(E)
        rot = (0,0,0)

    rotZ = me.orientation
    me.orientation = rot*rotZ

    controller.activate(grav)

main()
```

which roughly works until any angle goes over 180 degrees, and looks discontinuous then. I assume this comes from rotation_difference being discontinuous – [blender documentation on Math Types & Utilities](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_63_17/mathutils.html) does not say anything, and I have not thought enough about quaternionic representations yet to see if a continuous map would be possible – and I guess there is a more elegant way to achieve that the local Z orientation is continuously mouse-dependent, while local X and Y orientations depend continuously on some given vector, but how?

Comment: Rotations in 3D space can be quite tough. In my opinion, it's easiest to just put the time into understanding quaternions, and use those instead.

Comment: If using euler angles (instead of quaternions) one of the issues you may incur into is gimbal lock (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), which might cause quite some problems

Comment: Is it easy to try this out when you have Blender installed? (Not a Blender expert)

Comment: That link to the FPSController structure doesn't work anymore. Do you have a mirror?

Answer (score 4):

The consensus seems to be that you should accomplish such rotations using quaternions.

See this for the api: http://www.blender.org/documentation/249PythonDoc/Mathutils.Quaternion-class.html

See this for an introduction to the maths: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Quaternions

Answer (score 0):

There is a allign-function. If the game-object is called own it should be something like `own.alignAxisToVect(vector, 2, 1)` with 2 being the index for the Z-axis(x=0,y=1,z=2) and 1 being the speed of allignment (between 0 and 1)